# running a test/unit/RbcTest.php from a bash script directory not working

Tags: bash, jenkins

i have my RbcTest.php in the test/unit directory
in the bash script the word "test" is it a keyword?
i use the vi editor and it the word is in yellow, as soon as i change the test to tests the whole path is purple??

```
 export WORKSPACE=phoenix
 export SYMFONY=$WORKSPACE/usr/share/php/data/symfony
 (cd $WORKSPACE
    echo ${PWD}
    echo "6. Clearing the cache"
    ./symfony cc
    echo "7. Run unit test"
    php test/unit/RbcTest.php 
 )
```

warning and error:

```
  7. Run unit test
  PHP Warning:  require_once(/usr/share/php/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}()   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/unit/RbcTest.php:0
  PHP   2. require_once() /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/unit/RbcTest.php:3
  PHP   3. require_once() /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/bootstrap/unit.php:14
  PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php'    (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3
  PHP Stack trace:
  PHP   1. {main}() /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/unit/RbcTest.php:0
  PHP   2. require_once() /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/unit/RbcTest.php:3
  PHP   3. require_once() /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/b32b733b59ba6be9884da7427bee5c95/phoenix/test/bootstrap/unit.php:14
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash script `test` is indeed a keyword, although in this case vi is simply confused. You use `test`, for example, in `if` clauses:

```
if test -f /etc/fstab; then
  echo "/etc/fstab exists"
fi
```

I never use this keywoard because you can also use `[` instead, which I find prettier:

```
if [ -f /etc/fstab ]; then
  echo "/etc/fstab exists"
fi
```

To avoid vi highlighting it as a keyword, use strings:

```
php "test/unit/RbcTest.php"
```

As to why you're script is not working, it would help if you could clarify exactly what error you're getting. Maybe you can try this:

1. Mark your Bash script as an executable file: `chmod +x script.sh`
2. Specify the interpreter by putting this right at the top of your script: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: i have it as an executable, and i have #!/bin/bash at the top. this script is the script executed by Jenkins when you click on build. Whn i run this script from the command line all works fine. When Jenkins runs it i get a warning and error. please se main post thanks :)

Comment: A file included by a PHP script wasn't found. Do you know where you have your Symfony files? What is `test/boostrap/unit.php` including?